# Android PreferenceFragmentCompat custom layout list_container error

Tags: android, fragment, android-settings, preferencefragment

I want to add custom layout with Preferences List. but it gives me this error.

> Content has view with id attribute 'android.R.id.list_container' that
>   is not a ViewGroup class

Layout:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Styles:

```
<style name="BestMainTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/windowBackground</item>
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/BestAppSettingsTheme</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
</style>

<style name="BestAppSettingsTheme" parent="@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material">
    <item name="android:layout">@layout/fragment_preferences</item>
</style>
```

Code:

```
@Override
public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {

    setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Support Preference version 24 or later, Google has changed the needed id from `R.id.list_container` to `android.R.id.list_container`.

So just change your layout file to:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@android:id/list_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```